# json.net check if children exists

Tags: json, json.net

I have some json and parse the content using json.net. Firstly I use the JToken and split the fields from a post into a list of objects and then read the values from each. The problem is that some of these objects sometimes have the fields and sometimes dont and not sure how to prevent a nullexception error from being called. Here is the json sample:

```
{"id": "dfdksfjaisdfdsjfksdjdfsdafernd"}
{"body": "test data for parsing"}
{"object": { "summary":"hello test data you trouble maker", "id" :"problem stuff",
             "link": "http://testdata.com",
             "objecttype": "link"
}}
{"user": { "name": "Joe Somebody", "age":"43", "location": { "name": "outer space"},
         }
}
```

Now in some posts the location field is not present in user object which results in a null error in my code as shown below and also sometime the object object is in a different format as follows:

```
  {"id": "dfdksfjaisdfdsjfksdjdfsdafernd"}
  {"body": "test data for parsing"}
  {"object": { "object": 
             {"summary":"hello test data you trouble maker", "id" :"problem stuff",
             "link": "http://testdata.com",
             "objecttype": "link"
         }
  }}
  {"user": { "name": "Joe Somebody", "age":"43",
           }
  }
```

now if my code is as follows:

```
       Dim results As List(Of JToken) = jobj.Children().ToList

        If results.Count = 0 Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        For Each item As JProperty In results
            item.CreateReader()
            If item.Name = "id" Then
                id = item.Value
            End If
            If item.Name = "actor" Then
                author = item.Value("name").ToString
                location = item.Value("location").Item("name").ToString
                age = item.Value("age").ToString
            End If
            If item.Name = "object" Then
               htext = item.Value("summary").ToString
               csubject = item.Value("objectType").ToString
            End If
     Next
```

Then if location and object are different this code will not work. so how can I check to see if the location field is present and also if the object path is different with another object within it before the summary field.

EDIT:

Ok thought I figured it out with

```
 If Not item.Value("location") Is Nothing Then
  bla bla bla
```

Comment: ok never mind that did not work completely still getting null error for something.

Answer (score -1):

Ok I guess it did work and null exception from illformed json:

```
 If Not item.Value("location") Is Nothing Then
  bla bla bla
```

and the same for the object

```
 If Not item.Value("summary") Is Nothing Then
   bla bla bla
  else
     htext = item.Value("object").Item("summary").tostring
```